# ios - set / unset button background color

Tags: colors, uibutton

Using the method:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    mybutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

}
```

I can set the black color to mybutton. How can I toggle between two color, each time button is clicked?

Tx in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your h file initialize bool property

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL myBool;
```

In your m file put following line in viewDidLoad

```
self.myBool = YES;
```

Then in your IBAction,

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
 {
    if (self.myBool)
    {
       self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       self.myBool = NO;
    }
   else
   {
      self.button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
      self.myBool = YES;
   }
 }
```